# How to skip a print statement in loop

Tags: java

I have two classes named as Test1 and Test2.

```
class Test1{
    public void exe1(){
        System.out.println("Execute only one time");
        System.out.println("Execute iterations");
        System.out.println("Execute only last time");
    }
}

class Test2{
    public statuc void main(String args[]){
        Test1 ts = new Test1();
        for(int i=0 ; i<=3;i++){
            ts.exe1();
        }
    }
}
```

The ouput of this result would be :

```
Execute only one time
Execute iterations
Execute only last time
Execute only one time
Execute iterations
Execute only last time
Execute only one time
Execute iterations
Execute only last time
```

Is it possible in java that the output that i get should be  :

```
Execute only one time
Execute iterations
Execute iterations
Execute iterations
Execute only last time
```

I mean the 1st print statement should execute at very 1st time and then number of iterations may print and at the end my last print statement should execute.

Comment: Use switch or if statement

Comment: ***83 previous questions*** and you're still posting nearly-unformatted code?! Well, *that* shows respect for the community you're asking to help you.

Comment: You might need to pass in the current and total numbers of iterations to `exe1` so that it can know whether it is the first, last or other iteration.

Comment: The code doesn't so what you claim, it executes the loop 4 times.

Comment: and in java there is nothing like "statuc" and what you have printed in output will not match your code

Answer (score 3):

```
public void exe1(int i){
    if(i==0) System.out.println("Execute only one time");
    if(i==3) System.out.println("Execute only last time");
    else System.out.println("Execute iterations");
}

for(int i=0 ; i<=3;i++){
    ts.exe1(i);
}
```

Use i in your loop as a function argument.

Comment: I would pass in 3 also, so it isn't a magic number scattered through the code. Also, by the spec in the question, the first and last messages should be printed in addition, not instead of.

Comment: @Alex :- Instead of taking hard coded value as 3 , if i'm taking a list.size() then how can it executed ?
like for(int i=0;i==ls.size();i++) where ls is an instance arryalist and having 3 objects added to it.

Comment: @Littlebird if you have list with three objects and use "for(int i=0;i==ls.size();i++)", it will be iterate 4 times and not three, you must use for(int i=0;i<ls.size();i++) 
see my comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/30186059/4580058

Comment: @Littlebird In this case just replace "3" with "ls.size()" in both loop initiation and conditional statement

Comment: @AlexShutin: I tried it but working . I created another post can you please look into my code where i'm wrong ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30190753/how-to-print-statement-as-per-loop-condition?noredirect=1#comment48486722_30190753

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two parameters to check if the text should be printed or not

```
public void exe1(int counter, int totalCount){
   if (counter == 0) System.out.println("Execute only one time");
   System.out.println("Execute iterations");
   if (counter == totalCount) System.out.println("Execute only last time");
}

for(int i=0 ; i<=3;i++){
   ts.exe1(i,3);
}
```

Comment: This code will print "Execute iterations" 5 times instead of 3.

Comment: only 4 times :) then you must adjust the iteration code to i<=2, while the number of iterations is 4

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test1 {
public void exe1(boolean isFirst, boolean isLast) {

    if (isFirst) {
        System.out.println("Execute only one time");
    } else {
        if (isLast) {
            System.out.println("Execute only last time");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Execute iterations");
        }
    }
}
}

public class Test2 {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Test1 ts = new Test1();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            ts.exe1(true, false);
        } else {

            if (i == 3) {
                ts.exe1(false, true);
            } else {
                ts.exe1(false, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The output is not right. Iterations don't execute first and last time

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Test1{
      public void exe1(int i){
          If(i==0)
              System.out.println("Execute only one time");
          If(i>0 && i<3)
              System.out.println("Execute iterations");
          Else
              System.out.println("Execute only last time");

    }
}
```

By the way, next time please format your code in an adequate manner and check for mistakes. If you ran that as it is, it wouldn't compile.